# Using a functor as a stateful callback function in Python

Tags: python

If I have a function which takes a callback function as an argument, how can I create a functor object which can be used in place of a callback function, if that callback function takes some set of arguments?

## Context:

Kafka producers take a callback function.

```
producer.produce(
  topic=topic,
  key=key,
  value=value,
  callback=delivery_callback
)
```

```
callback_count = 0

def delivery_callback(error, message_payload):
    if error:
        print(f'{error}')
    else:
        global callback_count
        callback_count += 1
        # count the number of successfully
        # delivered messages
```

This callback function counts the number of successfully delivered messages.

## Problems with this design and proposed solution

The problems with this design are obvious - the use of global variables.

My first instinct was to design some kind of functor object, which perhaps might define `__call__` to make it callable.

```
class DeliveryCallbackCounter():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.count_callback = 0

    def __call__(self, error, message):
        if error:
            print(f'ERROR: Kafka: Message delivery failure: {error}')
        else:
            self.count_callback += 1

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'DeliveryCallbackCounter: callback count: {self.count_callback}'
```

This can be used in the following way, and indeed works.

```
delivery_callback_counter = DeliveryCallbackCounter()

producer.produce(
  topic=topic,
  key=key,
  value=value,
  callback=delivery_callback_counter
)
```

However, this solution does not work in quite the same way as the previous option, because the class `DeliveryCallbackCounter` is not static. Previously, when using a function as the callback function, rather than a functor (class) the modified data `count_callback` was a global variable with static lifetime.

With a functor, we have something slightly different, and it would be possible to create many instantiations of the class `DeliveryCallbackCounter`.

Python classes have something similar to static methods which are indicated by the `@classmethod` decorator.

Is it possible to reproduce the same semantics as offered by the "function option" by building a "static class" in Python? I am not familiar enough with Python to know how to do this.

Comment: The usual solution is to use a `lambda`.

Comment: And if you need to update state, use a method of an instance: `callback=delivery_callback_counter.methodname`

Comment: Your desire to avoid global variables is admirable, but your "solution" seems to be to turn them into static variables. A static variable on a class is still global; it avoids using the scary word "global" but has all of the same problems. Either pass around explicit instances (as per your non-static solution) or just admit that you're using globals and accept that your codebase has a bit of a code smell in this situation.

Comment: Why is the *ability* to create multiple instances of `DeliveryCallbackCounter` a problem? If you only need one, then just create one.

Comment: If you *really* want to hide the counter, use a closure. The hoops you have to jump through to modify a non-local variable inside another function are far greater than what you need to do to modify a global variable, a class attribute, or an instance attribute.

Comment: I don't disagree with any of the above comments. My question was more about how it could be done rather than whether actually doing it is the best possible solution. I probably agree that using a lambda with a local capture variable or only creating a single instance of a functor class would be the most sensible, straightforward and obvious approach.

Comment: (Actually, I rescind my closure recommendation. It hides the counter so well that it's extremely difficult to even see its current value, much less modify it :) )

Comment: @chepner Thinking about it, in this case that wouldn't be a nice solution anyway because it would involve initializing something and defining a lambda a long way from where it is used. But that is specifically a "me" problem not something which is relevant in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class variable instead of a global variable:

```py
class DeliveryCallbackCounter:
    count_callback = 0

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __call__(self, error, message):
        if error:
            print(f'ERROR: Kafka: Message delivery failure: {error}')
        else:
            DeliveryCallbackCounter.count_callback += 1

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'DeliveryCallbackCounter: callback count: {DeliveryCallbackCounter.count_callback}'
```

Comment: This answers the OP's question, but as explained by Silvio Mayolo, this just replaces one global variable with another.  A static variable is a global by another name.

Comment: Yes, its global in the sense that there is only one `count_callback`, but also not, in the sense that the OP now has the chance to create new classes, each with their own `static` value, and create instances of the class for other callbacks. (btw, everything is "global" within the same process if you can reference it)

Comment: `DeliveryCallbackCounter.count_callback` vs `DeliveryCallbackCounter_count_callback`. If the OP knows enough to write a `__call__` method, they know enough to give their global variables different names. The purpose of static class variables isn't "to get rid of global variables" --it doesn't--but just to move them close to the code that uses and accesses it.

Comment: It's not global in the sense that it has its own namespace to live in, which is better than being a truly "global" variable. Thank you for the answer, I learned some new Python from this.

Comment: However I don't disagree with any of the comments posted under the question. This may not be the most obvious solution - I asked the question to learn more about what could be done rather than what the best solution in terms of architecture is. I think we all agree a single instance of a functor class or a lambda is the "most obvious" approach.